# IE7 on XP render the media="print" stylesheets

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-7, screen, media-queries

In my web page, I'm using 2 stylesheets :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen-layout.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print-layout.css" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

inside `print-layout.css` there is :

```
.ui-dialog * {display: none !important;}
```

When I viewed my webpage on IE7, it's supposed to ignore the `media="print"` one, but it didn't, it applied the `display: none`, causing all the elements to be hidden. And in the debugbar plugin for IE7, I can see that IE7 applied the `print-layout.css` file. How is that possible? or am I missing any requirements for using print on IE7?

Thanks :)

Comment: Forget IE7, it's the new IE6.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks : 'forget it' is the perfect solution, but the client demands it =]]...

Comment: Then why not explain to the client that IE7 is no longer a viable option to suppoort. The time it takes us to support vs the amount of users still using it is waaayy weighted in our favor ;)

Comment: why is ie7 supposed to ignore that style?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks : :D...haha  
alber : I want to know why too...

Comment: @albert : sorry I misunderstood your comment yesterday. It is supposed to ignore the media="print" stylesheet, because it's for print device only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax works even on IE7 but if you need to exclude that browser from applying your print style, just rewrite your last inclusion in this way:

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
   @import url('css/print-layout.css') print;
</style>
```

since IE7 hasn't implemented the media type on `@import` rule.

Otherwise just wrap the second inclusion in a conditional comment, like so

```
<!--[if (gte IE 8)]><!-->
   <link rel="stylesheet"... media="print" /> 
<!--<![endif]-->
```

so you include the print style for all browser except `IE < 8`.

---

As a side note: IE7 usage is globally `< 1%`:
see http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201211-201304

Comment: So IE7 just blindly apply the stylesheets, no matter what media type it is?

Comment: IE7 uses correctly the media print on the `style` tag, otherwise you wouldn't see any element (you set display: none to all UI-Dialog elements)