# Window.Print() functionality breaking in IE7 with screens with pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, internet-explorer-7

We have a print functionality on our application which we implement through JavaScript `window.print` where in we print those pages which have records to be displayed. Some of these pages have pagination which have records greater than 20.

The functinality works fine in almost all browers except IE 7, in which either the print popup does not open when the page has pagination or if it opens an empty page is printed.

Any pointers to deal with such a problem?

Comment: To add more info.. our wep pages display records fetched from a database and web services. We have impemented pagination when the records are more than 20. Whenever the records are more than 20 and the user click on the print button on the page window.print() is invoked. This works fine in all the browsers but when the user is using IE7 the page is not printed, sometimes the browser hangs and in other instances the print dialog box opens but then does print anything.

Comment: Without pagination is it working in IE7? Have you referred this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

If I had to take a guess based on what I can see, it is more then likely not the `window.print()` function at all. To print we usually would use conditional style-sheets to format the page for print `@media print` but this is not supported by IE7, however a conditional IE style-sheet with an `media="print"` attribute can force it.

The reason I say this is because IE is a dinosaur now, it does not play nice when it comes to re-rendering for something like printing, so a conditional style-sheet is critical to get proper functionality.

Though considering that IE is so outdated and that even things like jQuery is starting to remove support, I would not be to worried and just stick with the more modern browsers witch will save you a lot more time in the long run.

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333764/ie7-on-xp-render-the-media-print-stylesheets) shows another post similar to this one.

[Support of media queries](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), IE 7 is not even listed!